# Apache Kafka producer option on windows

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to **Apache Kafka** and running Kafka on Windows 7. Kafka publisher bat file is not supporting Zookeeper option. am using `broker-list` options that requires Broker IP and port.But Linux SH is supporting Zookeeper option. please help how to use Zookeeper option on Windows publisher bat.

### Windows Command

`kafka-console-producer.bat **--broker-list** localhost:9092 --topic test`

### Linux Command

`kafka-console-producer.sh **--zookeeper** localhost:2181 --topic test`

Answer (score 1):

Kafka producers are no longer communicating with Zookeeper and only targets Kafka brokers since a number of versions ago. You should be using `--broker-list` with both Linux and Windows console producer scripts now.

Comment: In this scenario, if my leader broker is down then I can't sent message. it has dependent with Broker. as per Kafka design, no dependency with Broker.  if I connect to Zookeeper that will find out the active broker. it will be good. please give additional details

Comment: The producer will send metadata requests to the cluster to find out the current set of available brokers and will become aware of changes to cluster membership dynamically. Since Kafka 0.8.2 this is the preferred way of connecting and gets rid of producer dependencies on Zookeeper. Since Kafka 0.9 there has been similar development for the consumer as well.

Comment: If I connect broker directly, then what is the use of Zookeeper. How can I control load balancing on Broker. if we connect Zookeeper, then only we come to know which one is active and no need to worry about balancing concept.

Comment: Zookeeper is used by the brokers for leader election and other things. Some notes about load balancing in the documentation here:


   http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#theproducer